# proximity Alert not fired

Tags: android

this is my first question here and i search answer but not found. 
i build simple app that that get the current position and will give alert if the i'm stand on specific position, but the alert not fired, please help. here my code :

MainActivity:

```
package com.lda.notyalert;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProximityIntentReceiver proximityIntentReceiver;
    private static final String PROXIMITY_ALERT = "com.lda.notyalert.ProximityIntentReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager;
        String svcName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(svcName);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        updateWithNewLocation(l);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
                locationListener);

        setProximityAlert();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
        proximityIntentReceiver = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(proximityIntentReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void setProximityAlert() {
        String locService = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(locService);

        double lat = 37.422006;
        double lng = -122.084095;
        float radius = 100f; // meters
        long expiration = -1; // do not expire

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, -1,
                intent, 0);
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration,
                proximityIntent);

    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        String latLongString = "No location found";
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
        }

        myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

}
```

this is the ProximityIntentReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver;

```
package com.lda.notyalert;


public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        if (entering) {

            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
        } else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                null, 0);
        Notification notification = createNotification();
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!",
                "You are near your point of interest.", pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification();

        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

        return notification;

    }

}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug?  Are you sure you're within the radius?  Have you increased the radius to make sure?  Are you sure your GPS is accurate enough to pinpoint this (and that it is on)?  Are there any errors or exceptions?  Have you tried firing an alert if you are not in the area, to make sure alerts work?